# How do i array[n][i] = 0 as an append in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-3.x, append, insert-into

I have the following code:

```
for i in range(w[n], W):
    array[n][i] = v[n]
```

In python this give an out of index error because I am not using append...how would I right the above in order to work in python???

All help will be appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: Where are your arrays? `v[n]`, `w[n]`? This much information is not enough.

Comment: Are you using NumPy's 2d arrays?

Comment: well not even worrying about that really it is just a syntax issue, because i want a two dimensional array like think of it like this:             for i in range(0, 10):
                knap_sac[n][i] = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use the name 'array' for an array. Even though it's not a reserved name in python, it's considered bad programming practice. A way to do what you want is like this:

```
myArr = [[0 for col in range(n)] for row in range(W)]
for i in range(w[n], W):
            myArr[n][i] = v[n]
```

The first line creates an array of [n][W] elements initialized to 0. It's the easiest way to achieve this in python without adding an extra dependency.

Comment: No, `array` isn't a reserved word Python, at least not in 2.7 or 3.3.

Comment: I'd agree, but mainly because `array` doesn't describe its real purpose.

Comment: Thanks I think that fixed it ...I got another error instead of list index out of range now I get list assignment out of range which I think has something to do with the other v[] array...